# Death of Chivalry quest - Black Knight armour problem

Tags: runescape

I need to wear the armour of the Black Knight, so I equip it, but Saradomin still keeps asking me to equip it: what do I do? How do I disable cosmetic overrides? I have destroyed the armour then put it back on, but still it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

There are three different things commonly referred to as "armour of the black knight", there's the Full Black set, there's the Black Knight Captain Armour and there's the Black Knight uniform. For this quest in particular the easiest way is to use the Black Knight Captain Armour, which you have aquired in an earlier quest and lays just next to the cabbage patch Saradomin stands on.

You must equip it, and only it (helm, cuirass, gown, gauntlets and boots).

Comment: yes i have done that i am wearing the helm cuirass gown gauntlet and boots and he is still asking me to equip it

Comment: i have nothing else on but that uniform

Comment: What I said was/is correct. It may be possible that it is indeed a cosmetic override ruining it for you (in which case go to your character menu -> gear -> disable all). If that still doesn't do the trick, attempt contacting Jagex as the question would have a bug on it. According to the official wiki, there are no known bugs on this quest (https://runescape.wiki/w/The_Death_of_Chivalry).